# How to stop link being followed until after jQuery .animate has complete?

Tags: jquery, animation

**back story:** I am designing a portfolio website for myself. on its home page, the logo is front and center but on the sub pages the logo is top & right.

I thought it would be a nice visual cue (upon clicking a link to a sub page) to use jQuery to animate the movement of the logo from the middle to the corner of the page.

**the issue:** the sub page loads faster than the animation completes.

**question:** is there some way to pause the link-following until after the animation has completed?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: While this certainly is a neat trick... any sort of wait between clicking and the expected action occurring will frustrate the user.  In this case, they'll see the logo move, then notice the entire page refreshes.  I know I'd be annoyed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You also need to return false or prevent the default action of the anchor click event otherwise the browser will just follow the href. Anyway agreed a live demo is better than 1000 words.

[See a live demo here](http://pastebin.me/493e1605948d4)

e.g

```
 $('#myLink').click( function(ev){
   //prevent the default action of the event, this will stop the href in the anchor being followed
   //before the animation has started, u can also use return false;
   ev.preventDefault();
   //store a reference to the anchor tag
   var $self=$(this);
   //get the image and animate assuming the image is a direct child of the anchor, if not use .find
   $self.children('img').animate( {height:"10px"}, function(){
       //now get the anchor href and redirect the browser
       document.location = $self.attr('href');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the animate function listed here: [(jquery doc)](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback)

It says that the callback should not be executed until the animation is complete.

> callback (Optional)   Function
>   A function to be executed whenever the animation completes, executes once for each element animated against.

Answer (score 1):

just in case anyone is interested in this variation...

i wanted **the link itself to be separate from the image that is animated**, i tinkered with the code a bit and now i have that working.

the javascript/jquery:

```
print(" $(function()
    {
        $('#myLink').click( function(ev){
            //prevent the default action of the event, this will stop the href in the anchor being followed
            //before the animation has started, u can also use return false;
            ev.preventDefault();
            //store a referene to the anchor tag
            var $self=$('img#myImage');
            var $link=$('a#myLink');
            //get the image and animate
            ($self).animate( {height:"10px"}, function(){
                //now get the anchor href and redirect the browser
                document.location = $link.attr('href');
            });
        });
    });
");
```

the markup:

```
print("<body>
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.co.uk">LINK</a>

<img id="myImage" src="http://www.derekallard.com/img/post_resources/jquery_ui_cap.png"/>
</body>");
```

that said, i likely ugly'd up the code. so my apologies there.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write any functions, just use the built-in jQuery event method event.preventDefault() (this was perhaps not available at the time this question was posted).

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#thelink").click( function(){
  $(this).animate( { animation stuff }, "medium", "easeboth", function(){
    document.location = $(this).attr('href');  
  });
 });
```

Or when the link is not animated but the image (as your question states):

```
 $("#thelink").click( function(){
  $("#theImg").animate( { animation stuff }, "medium", "easeboth", function(){
    document.location = $("thelink").attr('href');  
  });
 });
```

Comment: hi, sorry, but im quite a javascript/jquery novice and i can't make heads or tails of this part of your answer: 

document.location = $("thelink").attr('href'); 

i tried this, but doesn't seems to be right: 

document.location = $("http://google.com").attr('href');

would it b possible to give ex?

Comment: this will not stop the client following the link unless you prevent the default action or return false from the click handler

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably don't want to hear this but what you are doing is a big no-no in terms of usability.

You want to create a cool effect and in so doing slow down your user's experience. Nowadays web visitors are very busy and when they click on a link they want to get there asap. You will lose a percentage of visitors in the process and will aggravate many others just for the sake of a little visual candy.

Answer (score 0):

simply return false in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Not every website is the same. On a portfolio site - perfectly acceptable to have little animations and interface "cool", on a tool like Google search, if the logo animated every time before we could use the search bar it would be retarded.