# jquery delay a link from being followed

Tags: jquery

I have a short css-based animation that I want to play out before a link is followed (a card that swooped in on page load swoops out after click). Currently, however, the page called loads too quickly. I want to be able to briefly delay the href from being followed.

Here's what I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#card").css("top","0px");
    $(".clickit").click(function() {
        $("#card").css("top","-500");
    });
});
```

The first line swoops the card in on page load. After that is the click call that modifies the CSS, but like I said there needs to be some kind of delay in there because the page loads immediately, instead of after the animation. The CSS that is modified looks like this:

```
#card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: -500px;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s;
}
```

(yes, I know this is webkit-only right now)

This is a problem very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351268/how-to-stop-link-being-followed-until-after-jquery-animate-has-complete) from 2008, but I know jQuery has been updated significantly since then, so I wanted to see if there was a  more modern solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to slow down the user's experience?  As a user this would get annoying *very* fast...

Comment: understood and noted. just humor me...

Comment: @Nick - Haven't you read *The Charge of the Light Brigade*?

Comment: @patrick - Aye, it was required reading in AP english in highschool I believe, along with the entire back story.

Comment: @Nick - Well then there's your answer. ;o)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're using `.css()` and `-webkit-transition:`, you'll need to use a `setTimeout()` to delay the new location.

**Try the live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2WJH9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#card").css("top","0px");
    $(".clickit").click(function() {
        $("#card").css("top","-500px");  // Added px to make it work, 
                                         //   or get rid of quotes -500
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

             // Delay setting the location for one second
        setTimeout(function() {window.location = href}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

The `setTimeout()` will delay the `window.location` from being set for 1 second (1,000 milliseconds). If you want to match the `.5` seconds from `-webkit-transition:`, then change it to 500.

- `.setTimeout()` - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 5):

You can preventDefault() on the link then use jQuery's animate function to perform your CSS transitions, following the link after the animation has completed.

```
$('.clickit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#card').animate( { top: '-500px' }, 500, function() {
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

Comment: Agreed.  You don't need to setTimeout, just use the callback function when the animation is complete,  Thank you, Random citizen!

Answer (score 2):

> This is a problem very similar to this question from 2008, but I know jQuery has been updated significantly since then, so I wanted to see if there was a more modern solution.

Nope, still the same answer. Cancel the event, then load the location yourself later.

Comment: Thanks. So here's my attempt at adapting that... but it's not working. Still just loading the href right away:


 $(".clickit").click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var $self=$(this);
  $self.css("top","-800");
   document.location = $self.attr('href');
 });