# Delay href click, but not with SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to track the outbound links via google analytics, and [Google suggests using this](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, action);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
  }
</script>
```

Which is fine, except, my outbound links are to be opened in a new tab, and I am (naturally) using a `target="_blank"` for that..

but, the `setTimeout` method takes that away, and opens the link in the same page..

I've tried using `window.open()` but I am worried that it will be blocked by browsers..

So, is there anyway that I can execute this js function, and delay the click for just a little while? (100ms as google suggests)?

Thanks.

---

I've looked at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032182) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351268) like this on SO, but they don't deal with opening in new tab/window.

Comment: why not simple list on the click and use ajax to post it (in fact trackevent is async), leave the link alone let it do whats normal of for a link, this mean backwards compatibility and you still get your information.

Comment: Hi @AbstractChaos, can you please explain a bit further? I don't understand what you mean by, "why not simple list on click and use ajax to post it" - thanks.

Comment: Yh does sound a bit like broken English huh, As answer below does it calls a java script function as the user clicks the link but since your not cancelling the event it will continue and open a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to evolve the answer above here is a Jquery plugin that can provide listen a selection of links (based on your own criteria) and provide you a method for callback to them.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBhKx/)

So in the OP's case the setup could look like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank" data-category="Outbound">Google</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').trackOutBound(null,function() {
        var category= $(this).data('category');
        _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, this looks promising, will test it a bit and see if it works that way. thanks so much.

Comment: np, any questions let me know.

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly, I've tested it in a lot of browsers and it is consistent too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just remove the setTimeout() part of it.  So all it does is call the _trackEvent function.

Your links should execute both the javascript function and open the new window, if you just keep them something like:

```
<a href="example.com" target="_blank" onclick="recordOutboundLink(foo, bar)">Click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function recordOutboundLink(category, action) {
    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, action);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure this is what happens? I mean, as soon as the page gets a request to navigate, it will abandon all functions on the page and start navigation.. I think that's my theory, but, let me test it.. thanks.

Comment: Hi, so, you can see here - http://jsfiddle.net/ZNjPQ/ - it's not doing anything but going away to google..

Comment: @LocustHorde: It does do it, you just don't see it before it navigates. [Try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNjPQ/1/)

Comment: @LocustHorde, suggest you use Firebug's Net panel to check if there is a request made to Google when you click the link

Comment: Hi, lot of trials later, it is just random, sometimes it calls the script and executes it, but mostly it doesnt. I think it depends on the speed of the connection and system.. I was testing it with demo Analytics page and link And with fidler..

Comment: Without having tested it (yet) myself, it seems to me the delay is unnecessary for `_blank` links - it's only there because in regular links you navigate away from the page running the script, so the script stops execution. With `_blank` links you stay on the page, so scripts can continue their execution, no?

Comment: Just tested - requests fire off every time (in Chrome)

Answer (score -1):

I use this to keep the function waiting before continuing with the default browser behavior:

```
var wait_until = new Date().getTime() + 500;
while (new Date().getTime() < wait_until) {
    //Do nothing, wait
}
```